# Keep closing tag of li on same line ST2

Tags: html-lists, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sublime text keeps dropping closing tag of li on save.

```
<ul>
    <li>One
    </li>
    <li>Two
    </li>
    <li>Three
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there solution to keep it on the same line:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

This plugin is installed too:
https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify

Answer (score 0):

"That Plugin" is the main reason that is converting or breaking your code into two line. To fix it you have to remove this. Again read out more about that plugin.

> This is a Sublime Text 2 and 3 plugin allowing you to format your
>   HTML, CSS, JavaScript and JSON code. It uses a set of nice beautifier
>   scripts made by Einar Lielmanis. The formatters are written in
>   JavaScript, so you'll need something (node.js) to interpret JavaScript
>   code outside the browser.